# Get attribute of an entity based on foreign key

Tags: reactjs, field, react-admin

I am trying to get an attribute `file` of `vid` entity based on attribute `video` (present in different entity) which is basically an id of the `vid` entity. So far I have tried `<ReferenceField>` but with no luck.

```
<ReferenceField label="videoId" source="video" reference="vid" allowEmpty>
    <FunctionField label="Name" render={record => record ? record.file : null} />
</ReferenceField>
```

Any ideas how can I get the `file` attribute?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add a reproducible code sample with some data references. It would be easy for others to answer it.

Comment: @pritam I am not sure if I can actually add more to this. I have specified the problem and according to marmelab doc, the code sample I tried is supposed to solve it.